# Permutation of eigenvalues induced by a loop

Tags: reference-request, matrices, cv.complex-variables

A friend of mine just mention me what I think is a very fun phenomena and I would be very interested to learn more about it:

Let $A,B\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ two matrices. And let $\lambda_1(z), \lambda_2(z), \cdots , \lambda_n(z) $ the eigenvalues of $A+zB$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$. For a loop $\gamma : [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)=z_0$ we follow the continuous paths of the eigenvalues $t\rightarrow (\lambda_1(\gamma(t)),\cdots ,\lambda_n(\gamma(t))$. Surprisingly one can have $$\lambda_i(\gamma(0))\neq \lambda_i(\gamma(1)).$$In other word, the loop induce a permutation between the eigenvalues. The basic explanation is that $\lambda_i(z)$ is an analytic function only if the eigenvalue is not degenerate (and for some $z\in \mathbb{C}$, $A+zB$ may have non simple eigenvalues).

My guess is that there should exists a lot of books related to this but because I come from the probability community I don't know which "buzz word" I should write.  Could anyone give me a nice reference ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy ?

Comment: Canonical source in my mind: Kato's **Perturbation theory for linear operators**. Or for more applied mathematicians, Baumgärtel's **Analytic perturbation theory for matrices and operators**.